# How to handle Response when the I'm a expecting a url to download a file?

Tags: python, django, api

So I'm using a third party API to make my own, I'm expecting a download url back. But here the response is what I don't know how to handle. Any Help ?

```
class ListUserSearchView(APIView):

    def get(self, request):
        url = "baseurl"
        querystring = {"track_url": request.data.get('track_url')}
        headers = {
            "X-RapidAPI-Key": "apikey",
            "X-RapidAPI-Host": "host"
        }

        response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)
        data = response.text

        return Response(data)
```

Now I get error: Response.**init**() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: When you say "I'm expecting a download url back", what exactly does that mean?  Are you expecting a `Location` header response, or are you expecting a url in the body of the response, or what?

Comment: This would be the response {"url":"https://something-/2020-10-14/1602648740694.mp3"}

Comment: of course an example here

Comment: exactly this would be the location url to download the audio file

Comment: In that case, you can get the url with `response.json()['url']`

Comment: just passed    return Response(response.json())

Comment: and I get Response.__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: It's too confusing trying to read code in comments.  Update the question and include the full code and errors.  Otherwise we're just guessing at what you wrote and what the error was.

Comment: ok just updated it thanks

Comment: Please post the **full** error traceback, not just the final message.

Comment: it tells me I'm posting too much code id I enter the whole tracback

Comment: What kind of object is `Response`?  Can you show how you imported that class

Comment: ok thank you realised I was not importing  from rest_framework.response import Response but from .request instead

Comment: I have one more question ? How do I get the url I'm passing as a params in the query string ?  path('<str:link>/', ListUserSearchView.as_view()), and class ListUserSearchView(APIView):

    def get(self, request, link):
        url = "https://soundcloud4.p.rapidapi.com/song/download"
        querystring = {"track_url": f'{link}'}